# Bitwise operation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation

There is a solution available for doing bitwise operations. But, it converts the integers in binary number and then do bitwise operations. I already have the numbers in binary format. How do I carry out the bitwise operations for these numbers?
Ex. x = 10101, y = 11001
I want z = x or y to be 11101.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert decimal `10101` to binary `10101` by converting it to string then [`int(.., 2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) (2 => base 2):

```
>>> str(x)
'10101'
>>> int(str(x), 2)
21
```

Do operation you want (`|` => bitwise or):

```
>>> int(str(x), 2) | int(str(y), 2)
29
```

Then, convert it back to decimal, using [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) (or [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)  with format string `b` -> meaning binary representation) and `int`:

```
>>> format(int(str(x), 2) | int(str(y), 2), 'b')
'11101'
>>> int(format(int(str(x), 2) | int(str(y), 2), 'b'))  # back to integer
11101
```